# Taking bitwise '&' of arbitrary number of lists

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have an arbitrary number of lists that I want to take the boolean `&` of. For example for 2 lists, I have

```
x = [0, 1, 0, 0]
y = [1, 1, 0, 1]

[np.array(x) & np.array(y) for x,y in zip(x, y)]
[0, 1, 0, 0]
```

for 3 lists

```
z=[0,1,1,1]
```

I would have

```
[np.array(x) & np.array(y) & np.array(y) for x,y,z in zip(x, y, z)]
[0, 1, 0, 0]
```

etc.,

since my I have an arbitrary number of lists over which to perform this operation, what is the best method to achieve this?

Comment: why are you using `np.array` here??

Comment: `&` is a bitwise operator, not a boolean operator.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Likely because they've found out numpy neatly broadcasts `&`...

Comment: you can just use `np.bitwise_and.reduce([x, y, z])` if you are using numpy anyway

Comment: @AKX that doesn't make any sense in this case, though, since it isn't being used for broadcasting, it's creating a list of numpy scalars

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `zip` and `all`:

```py
x = [0,1,0,0]
y = [1,1,0,1]
z = [0,1,1,1]

output = [all(zipped) for zipped in zip(x, y, z)]
print(output) # [False, True, False, False]
```

If you do want to get `[0,1,0,0]` instead, use `int(all(zipped))` instead of `all(zipped)` (but this explicit recasting is redundant in most cases).

Comment: If bools are ok, you could also do `list(map(all, zip(x, y, z)))` (still longer than necessary, though :-P).

Comment: I like this one most, since I also have to do an `any(zipped)` for bitwise OR. And I do need the redundancy and thus had to cast it as an `int`. ,

Comment: @horcle_buzz Doesn't almost *every* solution shown have a natural counterpart for OR? In most you'd replace `and` with `or` and in mine you'd replace `min` with `max`. The one exception I see is the `prod` solution.

Answer (score 2):

or using np.logical_and

```
x = [0, 1, 0, 1]
y = [1, 1, 0, 1]
z = [1, 1, 0, 1]

np.logical_and(x, y, z).astype(int)
```

```
array([0, 1, 0, 1])
```

Comment: If the number of inputs is truly arbitrary (e.g. receiving a `list` of `np.array`s to `&` together), you can use `*` unpacking, of the outer `list`.

Answer (score 2):

With map and min:

```
x = [0,1,0,0]
y = [1,1,0,1]
z = [0,1,1,1]

output = list(map(min, x, y, z))
print(output)
```

Output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v0LBViHaQMdQx0DHIJarEsQzBPMMY7mqYHKGIB5XfmlJQWkJUCwns7hEIzexQCM3M09HoUJHoVJHoUpTk6ugKDOvRAOiTPP/fwA)):

```
[0, 1, 0, 0]
```

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Basic_operations) btw even mentions using min/max for and/or.

If you have a *list* of lists (as "arbitrary number" suggests, since you wouldn't want to use an arbitrary number of variables), you can use `list(map(min, *lists))`.

Answer (score 1):

`1` and `0` act like True and False so using `product` works

```
  lists=[x,y,z]
  np.prod(lists,axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import functools
import operator

x = np.array([0, 1, 0, 0])
y = np.array([1, 1, 0, 1])
z = np.array([0, 1, 1, 1])

print(functools.reduce(operator.and_, [x, y, z]))
```

Comment: if you are going to use `numpy` don't use `functools.reduce`!! That defeats the entire purpose

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `numpy` anyway, you can use:

```
np.bitwise_and.reduce(np.array([x,y,z]))
```

Example:

```
>>> x = [0, 1, 0, 0]
>>> y = [1, 1, 0, 1]
>>> z = [0, 1, 1, 1]
>>> np.bitwise_and.reduce([x, y, z])
array([0, 1, 0, 0])
```

But I wouldn't use numpy *just* for this. I'd probably go with j1-lee's answer.

Just for fun, here is another version of that answer:

```
>>> from functools import partial, reduce
>>> import operator as op
>>> list(map(partial(reduce, op.and_), zip(x,y,z)))
[0, 1, 0, 0]
>>>
```

because you are *mapping a reduction operation over the zipped data*

Comment: Not sure functools+operator is less overkill than NumPy :-P (And even j1-lee's seems like overkill)

Comment: @KellyBundy right, the point is simply that this pretty clearly describes what you are doing on a conceptual level, mapping a reduction operation

Comment: Hmm, ok. Maybe it's clearer than mine in that regard. Although if you think of min/max in boolean context as and/or, it's rather a straight-forward mapped reduction as well.